# Where is 'react' located?

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native version 0.63. In `App.js` it says

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
```

Where exactly is `react` and `react-native` and how does `App.js` know where to look? In the main project folder, there is a folder called `node_modules` which includes two folders called `react` and `react-native`, but as far as I can tell they don't export anything called `React` or `View` or `Text` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `React` is just the name given to the default export. Usually you could rename it as anything, although React requires that that namespace be included in order for it to function properly.

Go to the `index.js` file for each `node_modules` folder and you should see the root export for the package. In my latest React install, the `index.js` file exports from `react.development.js` in development, where you can find named exports for all the hooks e.t.c.

In production it exports from the minified bundle `react.production.min.js`.